# How to skip non-array variables from array_key_exists() in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I have the following code, which saves/sends the values and redirects to the address given in button:

Form.php

```
<Form Action="Process.php" Method="Post">
    <!-- some input fields (username, email, password, etc.) -->
    <Input Name="Save[Database]" Type="Hidden" Value="false">
    <Input Name="Save[Cookie]" Type="Hidden" Value="true">
    <Button Name="Save[WhereToGo]" Type="Submit" Value="Saved.php">Save</Button>

    <Input Name="Send[Database]" Type="Hidden" Value="true">
    <Input Name="Send[Cookie]" Type="Hidden" Value="false">
    <Button Name="Send[WhereToGo]" Type="Submit" Value="Sent.php">Send</Button>
</Form>
```

Process.php

```
//process the POST data and prepare them for saving/sending
...
foreach($_POST as $Collection){
    if(array_key_exists("Database",$Collection)){
        //send values into db
    }

    if(array_key_exists("Cookie",$Collection)){
        //save values into cookies
    }

    if(array_key_exists("WhereToGo",$Collection)){
        header("Location: ".$Collection["WhereToGo"]);
    }else{
        echo "Error";
    }
}
```

Everything works great if the visible input fields' (like username, email, password, etc.) value looks like `array[somevalue]`. But if the value is clear `somevalue` (as usual) the script echos error. How to avoid the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say if $Collection is an array, it works. If it's not an array, you get an error. So you'll have to check if $Collection is an array.

"How do you do that," you ask?

No idea, I don't know a lot about PHP, but I have [a good friend](http://google.com/search?q=php+variable+is+array). He says [this](https://www.php.net/is_array).

```
foreach($_POST as $Collection){
    if( is_array($Collection) ) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I had tried it before I asked, but it didn't work. I try it after your answer and it works! I'm confused little bit. But nevertheless thank you.